# SQL Count all records that has the same values for EVERY year.

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for SQL code that I can find counts for line items that possess the same membershiptyp every year. I'm in the process of trying to write a code that can give me a count for all records where they were non members for ALL years. I would need help with this For example

This is my query

```
select count(lname), 
Year, 
MembershipType

from Registrant

 where Year in      

('2014', '2013', '2012', '2011', '2010', '2009', '2008', '2007', '2006', '2005')

    and MembershipType = 'NonMember'


order by LastName
```

This is my data set

```
LName....Year.... Membershiptype
Smith......2014....Non-Member
Smith......2013....Member
Smith......2012....Member
Lee.........2014....NonMember
Lee.........2013....NonMember
Bob.........2014....NonMember
Bob.........2011....NonMember
Bob..........2010....NonMember
Harry........2010....Member
Harry........2011....NonMember
Harry........2012....Member
```

This should be my outcome

Count = 2

*This would be the outcome because both lee and bob were always nonmembers for every year. When I do these counts it pulls up all members that have the membertype "non-members" for each year. So for example, in my list of names the initial code would pull up harry, smith, lee and bob, because they were non members for one or more years. What I want it to do is count only Lee and bob because they were non members Every year. Please help

Read more: http://www.justanswer.com/computer-programming/8z44z-i-m-looking-code-find-counts.html#ixzz3TzerpMpA

Optional Information: 
 Language (or Software): SQL

Read more: http://www.justanswer.com/computer-programming/8z44z-i-m-looking-code-find-counts.html#ixzz3TzatPbvA

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to grab the distinct last names without memberships and remove those who have ever been a member (Except).

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    select distinct
        lname
    from Registrant
    where Year in ('2014', '2013', '2012', '2011', '2010', '2009', '2008', '2007', '2006', '2005')
        and MembershipType = 'NonMember'
EXCEPT
    select distinct
        lname
    from Registrant
    where Year in ('2014', '2013', '2012', '2011', '2010', '2009', '2008', '2007', '2006', '2005')
        and MembershipType <> 'NonMember'
) Inn;
```